# Issue when returning the first element in linked list before dequeuing it

Tags: c

I am learning the implementation of Linked list in C. I have an issue with my following implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct msg * Message;
struct msg{
    int SN;
    Message next;
};

Message dequeue(Message *head);
void new_msg(Message *head);

int main(){

Message M, head = NULL;

new_msg(&head);
M= dequeue(&head);
if(M != NULL) printf("Message %d has been deleted:", M->SN);

}


Message dequeue(Message *head)
{

    Message m, temp;

    if(*head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = *head;
        m = temp;  // To return the message before removing it from the queue
        head = head->next; // ERROR IS HERE
        free(temp);
    }

    return (m);
}

void new_msg(Message *head){

    Message m, last;
    m = malloc(sizeof(struct msg));

    last = *head;
    srand(0);
    m->SN = rand();

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = m;
    }
    else
    {
        while (last->next != NULL)
        {
            last = last->next;
        }
        last->next = m;
    }


}
```

I will extend my program to act as a queue which requires to return the first node in the queue ( i.e. head) before dequeuing it entirely but I keep getting this error:

```
/bin/sh -c 'make -j 8 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ hello - Debug ]----------
gcc -c  "/Users/CFC/Library/Application Support/codelite/test/hello/main.c" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.c.o -I. -I.
/Users/CFC/Library/Application Support/codelite/test/hello/main.c:38:20: error: member reference base type 'Message' (aka 'struct msg *') is not a structure or union
        head = head->next;
               ~~~~^ ~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Debug/main.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [All] Error 2
====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

in this line `head = head->next;` in this function  `Message dequeue(Message *head)`.

Kindly, can someone explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: Change `head = head->link` to `head = head->next`.  Also, note that in `main`, if `dequeue` returns a `NULL`, the `printf` will segfault.

Comment: @FriddyJoe Are you sure you have shown us the exact code you are compiling? That error does not match up with the code you have shown. Anyway, have you tried what CraigEstey has pointed out?

Comment: Yes, I copied it from the CodeLite console

Comment: @FriddyJoe Ok, then please show us where in your code you have `head = head->next` as shown in the error message.

Comment: I apologize for confusing you guys. Yes CraigEstey pointed out something good. I posted the updated version but still showing the same error message. Thank you again

Comment: `head` is of type `struct msg **`. You need to do `*head = (*head)->next;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message dequeue(Message *head)
{

    Message  temp=NULL;

    if(*head )
    {
        temp = *head;

        *head = temp->next;  // ERROR HERE
    //  ^____________________ you have to dereference the pointer head
        //free(temp); // do not free it 
    }

    return temp;
}



int main()
{
    Message M, head = NULL;

    new_msg(&head);
    M= dequeue(&head);
    if(M) // check if not NULL
    {
        printf("Message %d has been deleted:", M->SN);
       free(M); // now its time to free it
    }

}
```

Comment: Appreciate your explanation.